# OBIEE 12.2.1.4.0 compatible with Oracle database 19c?

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have issues connecting my pluggable database to Oracle Business Intelligence when I'm trying to create the schema in the setup configuration the error looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6v1l.png)
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle OBIEE 12c Certification Matrix, It can be install on Oracle 19c Database:
[image: OBIEE 12.2.1.4 Certification Matrix]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I managed to install it!